# How to load QJsonDocument from a file

Tags: c++, json, qt

Im trying to learn how to use JSON and Qt i have menaged and im having problem getting QJsonDocument from a file.The file opens correctly i can also see file's content with qDebug() but the QJsonDocument created from this file is always empty

```
 if(stdButton==QDialogButtonBox::Ok)
    {
       qDebug()<<"accept button clicked";

       QFile userList;

       userList.setFileName("users.json");
       userList.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

       //using this qDebug i'm able to see files content
       qDebug()<<QJsonDocument::fromJson(userList.readAll());

       //but this QJsonDocument is always empty
       QJsonDocument userDoc;
       userDoc=QJsonDocument::fromJson(userList.readAll());
       if(userDoc.isEmpty())
       {
           qDebug()<<"userDoc is empty";
       }
       qDebug()<<userDoc;
       accept();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> //but this QJsonDocument is always empty
> QJsonDocument userDoc;
> userDoc=QJsonDocument::fromJson(userList.readAll());
> ```

That's because there is nothing to read from the file since you have read everything from it in the previous call to `readAll()`.

You can store the data from `userList.readAll()` and use it repeatedly.

```
QFile userList;

userList.setFileName("users.json");
userList.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

QByteArray data = userList.readAll();
qDebug()<<QJsonDocument::fromJson(data);

QJsonDocument userDoc;
userDoc=QJsonDocument::fromJson(data);
```